# what is the storage mechanism for moodle on AWS (moodle by bitnami)

Tags: storage, moodle, bitnami, aws-marketplace

I have taken an moodle AMI from AWS MARKETPLACE (moodle by bitnami) and launched an instance ,
my instance is up and running and working fine, but if i upload any videos or images in that moodle, where will be my data gets stored. I didnot created any S3 buckets or RDS,

Please help me if any one had already took this aws moodle by bitnami in AWS Marketplace

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

The data is stored in the instance where Moodle is running. If you access the instance using a SSH connection, you can get the app's files from /opt/bitnami/apps/moodle/htdocs.

I hope this information helps.

Comment: hello Jota martos, How can we configure to store all our media uploaded through moodle to S3 buckets.?

Comment: That's something related to the application and you will need to follow its documentation to use s3 buckets instead of using the instance disk.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Moodle site running on AWS and my opinion is that hosting this way does not take full advantage of a cloud based solution. You may wish to consider using EC2 service to run the code, EFS service for moodledata files,RDS for a managed database, Eleasticache for Redis caching, ELB for load balancing to multiple EC2 instances and termination of https, S3 Glacier for backups. If you have  more one EC2 instance you can use spot instances to save money.